# How can I Ecrypt using public key generated by jpbc

Tags: java, encryption, public-key-encryption, elliptic-curve

I am using jpbc(Java pairing based cryptography) to generate public and private keys.

```
secret Key=random from Zn (for some n)  
private key=g^secretkey (g is generator)
```

The generated private key is 520970816610209807017211106072619643342231254982
and public key is 4364377476297398825794257780988969517972762758994254008863941913533830544083793244716093661347745129442432381929639153665437466547480708857597314131003216,6339898572588712728071523268489373098073453182596905335679653151242814037451740962958045848480557497628222698939931012677610106015750048131397924068665707,0

First Request:My first confusion is that why there are commas in public key? generator g also has comma separated values.

If I have integer m to encrypt, I suppose that it can be encrypted by:

```
 encrypted=m^public_key  
 decrypted=m^private_key
```

(Correct me if this is wrong (Is mod n required?))

Second Request: How can I encrypt m using those Comma separated public key?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why downvotes? Please at least suggest the mistake I made in asking...

Comment: *"How can I encrypt m using those Comma separated public key?"* - RSA and elliptic curves cannot be combined so easily. What is it that you want to do? Did you find a scheme that you want to implement? Have you looked into ECIES?

Comment: *"My first confusion is that why there are commas in public key?"* - Your secret key is a positive integer modulo n. Your generator is most likely element of the group G1 which is an elliptic curve group. Elements of such a group are points on that curve. Points have two components: x and y. That is why there is a comma in order to delimit the two components.

Comment: There are 3 components in public key, last one being 0. What is that? Thanks for the x and y point explanation. And yes I am trying to implement ORUTA (Secure auditing for shared data on cloud) which uses bilinear maps. I want to encrypt the message to be stored on cloud.

Comment: The last zero is probably the flag that denotes whether the point represents infinity.

Comment: So whether 0 represents infintiy or 1? And also how can that comma seperated value for encryption?

Comment: I've scrolled through the ORUTA paper and I haven't seen that the scheme provides encryption. It seems to provide digital-signatures. The scheme is quite complex, so what kind of answers are you expecting? Nobody is going to implement the scheme for you. But you can try it yourself and ask further questions about small parts of the scheme.

Comment: No no, I am not asking to implement the scheme, I am doing that and also I have asked questions on some techniques before. What I thought was to provide encryption to the data on the cloud using the same keys generated. But now I realize that for group to access shared encrypted data, I need some other technique. Thank you for solving the doubt of the commas in values and for taking efforts by going through the paper. Thank a lot.